# Grpc class generate Android Java

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers, grpc

when I am trying to generate my java classes withe the proto files its work but the class myserviceGrpc not generated I don't understand what

```
 
syntax = "proto3";


option java_package = "com.binaapps.identify";
option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_outer_classname = "ProcessProto";

package imageProcessing;

// The greeting service definition.
service Process {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc ProcessUnary (ProcessUnaryRequest) returns (ProcessUnaryReply);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message ProcessUnaryRequest {
    bytes imageData = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings.
message ProcessUnaryReply {
    ProcessedImageData processedImageData =1;
}

message ProcessedImageData
{
    bool hasFace =1;
    int32 facesCount =2;    
    repeated Point2d landmarks=3;
}

message Point2d
{
    int32 x =1;
    int32 y =2;
}
```

build.graddle (project)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.1'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15"
        classpath "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.9.3"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.1' apply false
    id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.9.1" apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(module)

```
protobuf {
    protoc { artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.19.2' }
    plugins {
        grpc { artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.47.0' }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java { option 'lite' }
            }
            task.plugins {
                grpc {
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I run in my terminal:

```
protoc --java_out=app/build/generated/ap_generated_sources/debug/out 
       --proto_path=/Users/binadev/Downloads/Identify/app/src/main/Protos
       /Users/binadev/Downloads/Identify/app/src/main/Protos/RemoteImageProcessingProtoV1.proto
```

Comment: gRPC and proto generation are two different steps.  It's normal and expected that just running protoc without any gRPC configuration won't generate the gRPC class.  What happens when you actually do a build through Gradle instead of just manually invoking protoc?